# C++ If statement won't function

Tags: c++, if-statement

```
//Writing a letter

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
string first_name;      //Name of addressee
string friend_name;     //Name of a friend top be mentioned in the letter
char friend_sex, m, f;  //variable for gender of friend

friend_sex = 0;

cout << "\nEnter the name of the person you want to write to: ";
cin >> first_name;

cout << "Enter the name of a friend: ";
cin >> friend_name;

cout << "Enter friend's sex(m/f): ";    //Enter m or f for friend
cin >> friend_sex;                      //Place m or f into friend_sex

cout << "\nDear " << first_name << ",\n\n"
     << "   How are you? I am fine. I miss you!blahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh.\n"   
     << "blahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh.\n"
     << "Have you seen " << friend_name << " lately? ";

//braces only necessary if there are more than one statement in the if function
if(friend_sex == m) {
    cout << "If you see " << friend_name << ", please ask him to call me.";             
}   //If friend is male, output this
if(friend_sex == f) {
    cout << "If you see " << friend_name << ", please ask her to call me.";
}   //If friend is female, output this

return(0);
}
```

This is what actually comes out:

```
Enter the name of the person you want to write to: MOM

Enter the name of a friend: DAD

Enter friend's sex(m/f): m

Dear MOM, 

        How are you? I am fine. I miss you! blahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh.
        blahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh.
        Have you seen DAD lately?
```

This program is simulating a short letter. Outputting a block of words is easy enough, but when I want some conditionals to be placed in the letter, I'm in trouble. Even though I've input the friend_sex (m/f) when the program asks me, the output from the if statement does not materialize. Why?

Comment: You don't seem to be setting "m" and "f" to any values for the comparison.

Comment: Try cout << friend_sex and see what it's set to.

Comment: BTW, is this homework? Then tag homework.

Comment: It's not really homework, I'm practicing out of a textbook. Not sure if that still applies, I'm new.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're testing `friend_sex` against the uninitialized character variable `m`. You probably want to test against the literal value `'m'`. It would be like having an integer variable called `seven` and expecting it to hold the value `7`.

Answer (score 3):

`char m, f`

This declares variables named m and f. Here m and f are the variable name, not the values are 'm' and 'f'. Right now they are containing garbage values.

You need to initialize them:

`char m = 'm', f = 'f'`

Or you can put char constant directly in the if statement instead of using variables m, f.

`if (friend_sex == 'm') {}`

Answer (score 1):

you check friend_sex aginst m and f which are not initialized.  you can check against the literal 'm' or 'f'

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing `friend_sex` to an uninitialized variable, `m`.  You should be comparing it to the constant `'m'`.  Note the single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to check something like `if (friend_sex == 'm')` instead of checking it against the variable `m`. Basically you need to check against the expected value.

Answer (score 1):

This is your issue:

```
if(friend_sex == m)
```

You're comparing two **variables** and not the contents you put into the `friend_sex` variable.

So if you change it to this:

```
if(friend_sex == 'm')
```

Now, this will check if the *content* of `friend_sex` is 'm'.